# Azure Data Catalog: Are there Rest APIs that expose Table and Column Profile of a Data Asset?

Tags: azure-data-catalog

I am trying to get the Data Profile of a Data Asset using ADC REST APIs but don't see any API(s) specifically that exposes the Data Profile information. Are there Rest APIs that expose Table and Column Profile of a Data Asset? If not, is this functionality included in road-map?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the GET API for the asset and it will retrieve the data profile as well. There is no specific API just for the data profile.

Hope this helps,
Monica